# Laravel 5.7 simple pagination

Tags: laravel, pagination, laravel-5.7

In our application, we have modules called Reports where in this report will show you the summarize of the module.

**Example**

```
General Journal Report - in this report will show you the summarize of the general journal module.
```

Now in our reports need to implement the pagination, having a problem applying the pagination in query builder.

**Controller**

```
$general_journals                   = GeneralJournalReportModel::getGeneralJournals();
$data['defined_gj']              = GeneralJournalReportItemsController::getDefinedGJById($general_journals);
```

I fetch all the general journal records and stored it in the variable general_journals then I passed it in another controller to do something else(such as putting some error handling when the column is null).

**Model**

```
public static function getGeneralJournals()
{
            return DB::table('general_journals as gj')
                ->select('gj.id as id',
                        'gj.number as number',
                        'gj.posting_date as posting_date',
                        'gj.remarks as remarks',
                        'gj.document_reference as document_reference',
                        'gji.debit_amount as debit_amount',
                        'gji.credit_amount as credit_amount')
            ->leftJoin('general_journal_items as gji', 'gj.id', '=', 'gji.general_journal_id')
            ->where('gj.company_id', Auth::user()->company_id)
            ->where('gj.approval_status', 3)
            ->orderBy('gj.id', 'desc')
            ->simplePaginate(5);
}
```

**View**

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 col-lg-12">
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover general-journal-report-table" id="gj-report">
            <thead class="thead-global">
                <tr>
                    <th id="pj_sequence">Sequence No.</th>
                    <th id="pj_date">Posting Date</th>
                    <th id="pj_op">Transaction No.</th>
                    <th id="4">Document Reference</th>
                    <th id="5">Remarks</th>  
                    <th id="6">Amount Due</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody class="general-journal-report-details">
                @if($defined_gj)
                <?php $counter = 0; ;?>
                <?php $total_debit = 0; ?>
                @foreach($defined_gj as $key => $value)
                    <?php $counter++;?>
                    <?php $total_debit += $value->debit ;?>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="pj_sequence">{{$counter}}</td>
                        <td class="pj_date">{{$value->posting_date}}</td>
                        <td class="pj_op">{!! $value->number !!}</td>
                        <td>{{$value->doc_ref}}</td>
                        <td>{{$value->remarks}}</td>
                        @if($value->debit == '0')
                        <td></td>
                        @else
                        <td align="right"> {{number_format($value->debit,2)}}</td>
                        @endif
                    </tr>
                @endforeach
                    <tr>
                        <td><b>Total</b></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td align="right"> {{number_format($total_debit)}}</td>
                    </tr>
                @endif
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    {{ $general_journals->links() }}
</div>
```

When I used the links() my button doesn't have any class.

Question: How do I put some class on the button of links?

NOTE: I tried this {{ $general_journals->links() }} but it only worked on the previous button(I want to also apply the class in the next button)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
{{ $general_journals->links('pagination::bootstrap-4') }}
```

Replace with your laravel bootstrap version.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to customize the pagination view, you can follow to this link https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/pagination#customizing-the-pagination-view